# How to get the top two elements using map reduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am learning Hadoop.
I am trying to solve following problem using map reduce:

Given a file containing records of doctor and corresponding patient he treated. Find the top two doctors, who have treated most number of patients.

**Eg.,**

### **Input:**

### Doctor   Patient

D4 P1

D2 P2

D3 P3

D4 P4

D1 P5

D4 P1

D2 P2

D3 P1

D2 P5

D2 P6

D2 P1

D2 P5

D4 P2

D2 P1

**Output:**

D2 7

D4 4

---

I am able to list all the doctors with their count of patient treatments. But not able to figure out how to get the top two doctors using MR?

```
package com.doctors;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class TopDoctors {

    public static class Mapper extends
            org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        @Override
        protected void map(
                Text key,
                Text value,
                org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable>.Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }

    public static class Reducer
            extends
            org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, IntWritable, IntWritable, Text> {
        @Override
        protected void reduce(
                Text key,
                Iterable<IntWritable> value,
                org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, IntWritable, IntWritable, Text>.Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable i : value) {
                sum += i.get();
            }
            context.write(new IntWritable(sum), key);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Job job = Job.getInstance();

        job.setJarByClass(TopDoctors.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    }
}
```

Please clarify.

Comment: you can use chain mapreduce  or  put  your sum  into MAP & compare

Answer (score 0):

I think this may  solve you problem
 put  your sum & doctor-number in TreeMap  and  write  in  `cleanup method`

```
  public static class Reducer  ......

#In your reduce class create a TreeMap
 TreeMap<Integer, String> TopN = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();


protected void reduce(......){
   #here  is  your  get sum code

 if (TopN.size() < 3) {  //TopN
     if (TopN.get(sum) != null) 
     { TopN.put(sum, TopN.get(sum) + "-----" + key.toString()); 
    } else {
     TopN.put(sum, key.toString());
     }
} else {
 // if map.size> N  add one  & remove one
 if (TopN.get(sum) != null) { 
    TopN.put(sum, TopN.get(sum) + "------" + key.toString()); 
     // 
    } else { 
     TopN.put(sum, key.toString());
    TopN.remove(TopN.firstKey()); 
     } 
     } // when you put your data in treemap, it will sorted by itself; 
     } 
 @Override 
 protected void cleanup(Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException { 
if (TopN != null && !TopN.isEmpty()) { 
     Set<Integer> keys = TopN.keySet(); 
    for (Integer key : keys) { outkey.set(TopN.get(key));
         outvalue.set(key); 
        context.write(outkey, outvalue); 
                             } } } }
```